# How to align jQuery UI selectmenu with buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I've been struggling with this for a while (I'm really not experienced with jQuery UI).

I'm trying to implement a jQuery UI that has a [selectmenu](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) next to some regular [buttons](http://jqueryui.com/button/). For some reason I can't understand, the selectmenu is mis-aligned; it's way higher up on the page than the buttons.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of mis-aligned UI elements]

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, it sure looks very wrong to me. I've been struggling for quite a while now but haven't been able to figure it out.

The markup is really very basic so I don't think it's very helpful to include it here., but it's all here: http://jsbin.com/afixij/10/edit?html,css,js,output. Widen the Output to see all three elements (the selectmenu, and the buttons Foo and Bar) on the same line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just apply `vertical-align:middle` to the dropdown which is made up of spans to get the buttons aligned properly with the dropdown.

```
#speed-button{
  vertical-align : middle;
}
```

**[Bin](http://jsbin.com/afixij/11/)**

It appears there is no option to provide a custom classname for select menu widget (It is bad if that is the case) as applying rule to a class would be much better. You could as well do:-

Apply a classname for the `select`

and in css provide a generic rule for any `.menu-button`s

```
.menu-button + .ui-selectmenu-button{
   vertical-align : middle;
}
```

**[Bin2](http://jsbin.com/afixij/11/)**

Comment: Not sure if you can add a custom class to the widget while initialization, if so setting the rule to a classname and using it here would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hm ... That looks better in your bin, but it didn't work in my actual code. What is `speed-button`? That name doesn't appear in your HTML, does it?

Comment: @unwind It seems like it adds `-button` to the id, I am not sure if you can provide a classname to the widget though... Seems like there is no option to it. SO whatever id you are using you may want to add `-button` to the rule.

Comment: Thanks, that actually works. I'm glad I finally asked, I would never have figured that out myself.

Comment: @unwind You are welcome. I have provided another option which probably is better than dealing with ids.

Answer (score 2):

It might actually be easier to make the actual buttons (not menu) up by using

`<button style="vertical-align: top"></button>`

It can be inlined and creation of a custom class isn't required.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I applied was to place the content I wished to be vertically aligned in a `display: flex` entry.  For example:

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
    ... other elements here
</div>
```

for more details on this display type, see this excellent discussion:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the marked answer, there is a way to obtain the jquery object the selectmenu creates.  Make sure you initialize the selectmenu first or it won't work.

```
$("#speed").selectmenu();
$("#speed").selectmenu("widget").addClass("fixAnnoyingSelectAlignmentClass");
```

CSS:

```
.fixAnnoyingSelectAlignmentClass
{
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```